# Kusto how to select the latest record with the same id in a group of daily records

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

We query timeseries data for the last 7 days.
One user (defined by user id) may send several records in one day.

We want to get the latest record of that day per each user.
How to write it in Kusto?

Current table schema is like this:
[image: example data table with columns UserId, time, Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4 and 6 records]

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use [`summarize arg_max()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction) for that:

```
datatable(uid:int, dt:datetime, c1:int, c2:bool, c3:string, c4:int)
[
    1, datetime(2020-11-14 00:00:10), 12, true, 'exception', 2,
    1, datetime(2020-11-14 00:00:20), 21, false, 'well', 4,
    2, datetime(2020-11-07 00:00:08), 1, true, 'well', 5,
    3, datetime(2020-11-08 00:03:20), 3, false, 'exception', 2,
    2, datetime(2020-11-08 00:00:20), 13, false, 'well', 24,
]
| summarize arg_max(dt, *) by uid, startofday(dt)
```

```
    uid dt                      dt1                     c1  c2      c3   c4
    2   2020-11-07T00:00:00Z    2020-11-07T00:00:08Z     1  true    well        5
    3   2020-11-08T00:00:00Z    2020-11-08T00:03:20Z     3  false   exception   2
    2   2020-11-08T00:00:00Z    2020-11-08T00:00:20Z    13  false   well       24
    1   2020-11-14T00:00:00Z    2020-11-14T00:00:20Z    21  false   well        4
```

Comment: Sorry, I modified the sample data later. Actually according to your code, if uid 1 user send a data on 2020-11-7 and send two data on 2020-11-14, it will only get the latest data on 2020-11-14 and it's not right becasue I want to keep the latest data for one user in everyday!

Comment: Answer updated per (my understanding of) your update to the question

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help. That's exactly what I need!